# How to compare if the last trail of two URLs match?

Tags: google-sheets, comparison

I have tried to create a spreadsheet which lets me know if the last trailing step of two URLs are matching. (In case you are wondering: It is for redirect mapping because when I have old URLs and match them to a new structure the last trail stays the same more often than not.)

The said spreadsheet is working more or less and can be found here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m3E5NQYSUGe4Kxn4BrpcgWj4WhotKG88JCx93ER3U1c/edit?usp=sharing

I did the following:

1. Pull old and new URLs in two separate sheets (oldcrumb/newcrumb)
2. Split the URLs in these sheets into separate cells splitting at every "/"
3. Compare the last filled Cell in a Row between the two sheets

Unfortunately my solution is somewhat clunky. For about 600 initial rows I need another 1200 rows because I use 2 different sheets and also use split formula to get hands on the last trail.

Also I have just implemented comparison for a certain range (Rows I to H in the split row sheets) of trailing position with several IF-conditions. If URLs are supershort or superlong, nothing will be displayed in the "Last trail matching?" row.

Also at some point I get a warning because I would reach the maximum amount of usable cells in Google Sheets (around 200000 or so?).

So is there any more elaborate/elegant way to do what I did in a super awkward and heavy loaded approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula does it:

```
=regexreplace(A2, ".*/", "")=regexreplace(C2, ".*/", "")
```

Here, regexreplace removes everything up to (and including) the last slash, because `.*` means any number of any characters. So the equality is tested between the tails after the last slash.

Also works as an array formula:

```
=arrayformula(regexreplace(A2:A11, ".*/", "")=regexreplace(C2:C11, ".*/", ""))
```

or an array formula that allows for blank row in the input range:

```
=arrayformula(if(isblank(A2:A), "", regexreplace(A2:A, ".*/", "")=regexreplace(C2:C, ".*/", "")))
```

Comment: Awesome solution. Thank you! Question: When I want to set it up as a template with empty rows, the arrayformula displays #REF! error. It only works as long as I have filled in all declared rows. How to bypass it so nothing is displayed if rows are empty but the formula is applied when rows are filled?

Comment: Perhaps something like this as an array: `=IF(ISBLANK(A2:A10000),"",regexreplace(A3, ".*/", "")=regexreplace(C3, ".*/", ""))`

Comment: Yes, I edited such a formula in. You don't have to put "10000" in there, A2:A is simpler and more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a compare method using [lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Something like:

```
/**
 * Added for use as a custom function
 * @customfunction
 */
function compareurl (oldurl, newurl) {
  var a = oldurl.slice(oldurl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  var b = newurl.slice(newurl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

  return (a == b) ? true : false;
}
```

It finds the last `/` and creates a new string from the last token in the url to compare

**edit** Just noticed you may not be using apps scripts. Would still go with a [Custom Function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) and the above method. Then use `=compareurl()`

Comment: Repeating a custom function in 600 rows (as the OP mentions) is not great in terms of performance. Google Sheets have built-in functions for regular expressions that handle text processing more efficiently.

Comment: yea, I answered thinking in terms of a script solution instead built-in functions - having assumed a script was reading in the urls, splitting them and then trying to get the last cell values etc. I dont click on random spreadsheet links and am unaware of how that step was being performed.